# Bash: ${$(mycommand)%suffix} doesn't work to trim suffix from mycommand output

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I am trying to change the directory to the remote location of my git repository. I am using the command:

```
cd ${$(git remote get-url origin)%.git}
```

The command doesn't work:

```
bash: ${$(git remote get-url origin)%.git}: bad substitution
```

I don't understand why this isn't correct. Is it because of the `$()` instead of using a variables name? If yes why? How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use nested string substitution in `bash`.

Instead, you can use this one-liner:

```
cd $(git remote get-url origin | sed 's/\.git$//')
```

Comment: I like that too. Which is probably how I would do it if I were in that circumstance.

Comment: It's a one-liner, but induces an unnecessary subshell, not to mention the external tool instead of a shell built-in..

Comment: It is just a matter of preference, `sed`  is not bash builtin but still available on every `*nix` system

Comment: It's available, I'm just saying it's unnecessary performance overhead (at least for such simple tasks as suffix removal).

Comment: What kind of performance gain we are taking about here in removing `.git` from end :)

Comment: In this case, milliseconds. Likely insignificant. In a large loop, probably noticeable. Just a matter of setting an example. Why would you prefer `sed` over a `bash` built-in?

Comment: I seriously doubt if 2 commands can give milli-seconds gain over `sed`. In my quick benchmarking both approached took 10-11 ms each time.

Comment: For the complete pipeline (git+sed vs. git+bash repl) I'm seeing 1-2ms gains (5-6 vs. 3-4 ms). In a loop (x1000), consistently 200ms gains. If we look only at substitution (sed vs. bash) without git call, the difference is 800ms vs. 9ms.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a *command substitution* within a *parameter expansion with substring removal*. You need a two-step:

```
tmp=$(git remote get-url origin)
cd "${tmp%.git}"
```

That will eliminate the bad substitution.

[Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) itself operates on a [shell parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) (including shell variables referenced by name, positional parameters, etc). So if you are using `%.git` to remove the `.git` from the right-hand side, it must be contained in some variable, e.g. `tmp` above, then the parameter expansion works as it is intended.